# Serve file to user over http via php

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

If I goto http://site.com/uploads/file.pdf I can retrieve a file.

However, if I have a script such as:

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

//require global definitions 
require_once("includes/globals.php"); 
//validate the user before continuing 
isValidUser(); 
$subTitle = "Attachment";   
$attachmentPath = "/var/www/html/DEVELOPMENT/serviceNow/selfService/uploads/";
if(isset($_GET['id']) and !empty($_GET['id'])){
    //first lookup attachment meta information 
    $a = new Attachment(); 
    $attachment = $a->get($_GET['id']); 
    //filename will be original file name with user name.n prepended 
    $fileName = $attachmentPath.$_SESSION['nameN'].'-'.$attachment->file_name; 
    //instantiate new attachmentDownload and query for attachment chunks 
    $a = new AttachmentDownload(); 
    $chunks= $a->getRecords(array('sys_attachment'=>$_GET['id'], '__order_by'=>'position')); 


    $fh = fopen($fileName.'.gz','w');                                                      
    // read and base64 encode file contents 
    foreach($chunks as $chunk){
            fwrite($fh, base64_decode($chunk->data));   
    }
    fclose($fh);

    //open up filename for writing 
    $fh = fopen($fileName,'w');     
    //open up filename.gz for extraction                                
    $zd = gzopen($fileName.'.gz', "r");
    //iterate over file and write contents 
    while (!feof($zd)) {
            fwrite($fh, gzread($zd, 60*57));    
    }
    fclose($fh); 
    gzclose($zd);
    unlink($fileName.'.gz'); 
    $info = pathinfo($fileName); 

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.Mimetypes::get($info['extension']));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($fileName));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($fileName);
    exit();
}else{
    header("location: ".$links['status']."?".urlencode("item=incident&action=view&status=-1&place=".$links['home']));   
}


?>
```

This results in sending me the file, but when I open it I receive an error saying:

```
"File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported"
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when you don't retrieve the `Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Length` from code and instead set it manually to that specific file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd start by checking the HTTP headers.  You can do this in Firefox easily using the "Live HTTP headers" extension; not sure about equivalents in other browsers offhand.  This will let you verify if the header is actually getting set to "application/pdf" and whether your other headers are getting set as well.

If none of the headers are getting set, you might be inadvertently sending output before the calls to `header()`.  Is there any whitespace before the `<?php` tag?

Comment: The live http headers helped, although it was not a header problem I realized I had a typo... readfile($file) should have been readfile($fileName).  Thanks and sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure application/pdf is the header your browser is actually seeing?

You can check that out with various HTTP dev tools, for instance [HTTP Client](http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/) for the Mac or Firebug for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one and it works.

```
if(file_exists($file_serverfullpath))
{    
   header("Pragma: public");
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("Cache-Control: private", false);

   //sending download file
   header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); //application/octet-stream is more generic it works because in now days browsers are able to detect file anyway
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_serverfullpath) . "\""); //ok
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_serverfullpath)); //ok
   readfile($file_serverfullpath);
}
```

Comment: I have tried application/octet-stream and result in the same problem.

Comment: Did you try sending the headers in the SAME ORDER of my example?

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending "error_reporting(0);". I found this in the comments at http://php.net/readfile (where you took this example from).

Another thing that could be a problem is your file size. There have been issues reported in the past about PHP5 (we're talking 2005 here, so i hope this is fixed by now) having trouble reading files >2MB. If your file size exceeds this you may want to verify that it reads the whole file.

Comment: Files should be less than 500KB so size should not be a problem.