# php pdf download getting corrupt

Tags: php

I have a code which force download a pdf file. Code below

```
$file_name = 'Bv_Ebook.pdf';
$file_url = 'http://' .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/sites/default/files/'. $file_name;
header('Content-Type: text/html');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

This code works on our beta server and the pdf is downloaded and can be opened.

On our live server same code downloads the pdf but pdf file cannot be opened, it says:

**Unable to open document**
File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported

I have gone though [force download pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682929/force-pdf-download-with-php-file-corrupt-on-windows) and [apache headers setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610746/serve-file-to-user-over-http-via-php) but nothing seems to work.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: `Content-Type: text/html` ... you sure about that? Perhaps "application/pdf"?

Comment: Even application/pdf is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check file permission using is_readable() to check if the file is accessible or not. If accessible then check below :

Can you please try to modify your headers to the following:

```
//We'll be outputting a PDF.
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

//PDF name.
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
```

Then do a file read or what ever, in my case I have used file_get_contents(file_path) + echo to display the content and worked as a charm.

Comment: No application/pdf is also not working. text/html is working on beta server. I think this has something to do with apache settings!

Comment: Do you see a lot of text displayed on the screen then. The content of the PDF file should be outputted still.

Comment: Normally Apache has nothing to do with it, you output the document and the headers. Then the browser manages the file. Apache is just a webserver. Please make sure that document content is being displayed first. If not please checl the document path

Comment: Actually i am redirecting to another page simultaneously so dont know if it is writing any text. FYI in chrome developer tool it is showing as "(canceled)"

Comment: just disable redirecting and test.  See if you're reading the file or not

Comment: Thanks...i disabled the redirect but still it is not printing anything. Also I have given 777 permission to the pdf file.

Comment: Use PHP's is_readable function and pass it the path of the file you want to output.  is_readable("path_to/myfile.pdf"); and check the return value if is false then you're trying to read from the path

Comment: Thanks.... by checking is_readable i got to know that file is not accessible(although I have given 777 permission:( .So I changed the location of the file to root folder and it started working.